# Outputting information from a related model Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two different classes with different information - `Cards` and `Card Documents`.

In the database, these are stored in Cards - id, type, comments

Card Documents contains card id (foreign key of Cards) and filename as this is part of a file submission feature. Basically, I want to output the filename along with the Card information. I have tried outputting it by using this - {{ $card->files()->filename }} and it appears with this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::files()`.

I was wondering if this may be an issue with the models below:

Card model class:

```
public function documents()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CardDocuments::class);
    }
```

CardDocuments model class:

```
    public function files()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Card::class);
    }
```

Don't know if I've got the relationship between the two model classes wrong?

Comment: in cards table has a `filename`  field?

Comment: No because I'm adding the ability to upload multiple files for a single card so it would show multiple entries in in the card_documents table but not in cards as I don't think it would make sense.